# how easyrtcid is generated in demo audio only chat. Please give a code walk-through

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, webrtc

I am using `easyrtc` webpage to check the demo audio only chat. Its working fine.While connecting  `easyrtcid` variable is set to random string.

Is it possible to set/map our username to `easyrtcid`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set your username using easyRTC.

```
easyRTC.setUserName(userName);
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/EricDavies/6132815) is an example of how you can set username at the client side and other user can retrieve the username.

Happy Coding

Comment: how can i change auto generated id in easyrtc video call(demo_audio_video_simple).and how to restrict, only two users can connect? please help me how to do this?